# Get Data using Redux with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

So I just started learning hooks and I'm trying to use Redux with them. Ive been trying redux new api but now I can't seem to get the data that I want. When I do console.log() I see the promise getting resolved and inside the [[PromiseValue]] I see the data but how do I get it out of there into my Component.

```
const Main = ({props}) => {
 const [cloth,setCloth]=useState([])
 const items = useSelector((state) => state);
 const dispatch = useDispatch()
 let getItems = getAllItems(
    () => dispatch({ type: 'GET_ITEMS' }),
    [dispatch]
  )
 console.log(getItems)
```

here is the pic of my console.log()[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first to use redux with async actions you need to use `redux-thunk` middleware:

```
npm i redux-thunk
```

and then use it like so:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

now for the actions here a simple example:

first action to fetch Items and then action to set Items in store:

//actions.js

```
const setItems = (payload)=>({type:SET_ITEMS,payload})

export const fetchItem = ()=>{
return dispatch =>{
axios.get("/items").then(response=> 
dispatch(setItems(response.data))).catch(error=>throw error)
  }
}
```

//reducer.js

```
const state = {items:[]}

export default function todosReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_ITEMS":
      return {
        ...state,
        items: payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

now from react component we fetch items on mount :

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react"
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from "react-redux"
import {fetchItems} from "action.js"

const Items = ()=>{
const items= useSelector(state=>state.items)
const dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(()=> dispatch(fetchItems()),[])

return items?items.map(item =><p key={item.name}>{item.name}</p>):<p>items not available</p>
```

hope this what you are looking for.

Comment: Completly did it for me thanks alot before I used promiseMiddleWare to do async but thunk seems to really simple.